# Random Password Generator

Tags: c#, winforms, random, passwords, ascii

I am attempting to write a random password generator. I am in the early stages and am running into a few problems. With the below code and screenshot you can see that I get a very predictable string (the string of 2's). Every time I receive a string filled with only one kind of number. How should I edit my code to generate a better password string? (other than including more than just numbers)

[image]

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int characters = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
    string password = "";

    for(int i = 0; i <= characters; i++)
    {
       password = password +charGen();
    }

    label2.Text = password;
}

private char charGen()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    char randomNumber = Convert.ToChar( random.Next(48, 57));
    return randomNumber;
}
```

}

Comment: Its recommended not to manually create such functions. Instead use the built-in functions of c# like GUID

Comment: @SidharthMudgal GUIDs are not random

Comment: On a side note, what should I limit the random.Next range to in order to provide only commonly accepted password characters?

Comment: @Blorgbeard You mean, "certain types of GUIDs are not random".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random number generator only generating one random number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

Comment: @millimoose no type of GUID is completely random, but yeah ok some have some randomness. They are also generally represented as hex, which gives you a high characters/bits ratio - so not too much fun to type as a password.

Comment: Please abandon this project now, before you are tempted to use it to generate real passwords and get your identity stolen.

Comment: @Blorgbeard For all practical intents and purposes, "some randomness" is the same as "random". A version 4 UUID will have 120 random bits (assuming a true RNG), which is more than enough for a secure password. You're right that it's annoying to type, but that's not merely a factor of character/bits ratio. (E.g. Diceware passphrases are thought to be easy to remember and easy to type, but use a whole word of up to 6 characters for 12 bits of randomness.)

Comment: @finnw how will this project be any worse than using some other password generator? I admit in the question that this isn't very far in.

Comment: @jth41 Some other password generator will probably use some `SecureRandom` (this is the Java class, it may be called differently in C#) so that the password is really secure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just keep the `random` in the class scope:

```
Random random = new Random();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int characters = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
    string password = "";

    for(int i = 0; i <= characters; i++)
    {
       password = password +charGen();
    }

    label2.Text = password;
}

private char charGen()
{
    char randomNumber = Convert.ToChar( random.Next(48, 57));
    return randomNumber;
}
```

Currently it's seeded to practically the same value each time you call `charGen`.

Comment: It's probably seeded to **exactly** the same value. It's somewhat unlikely (~10% chance, ignoring algorithm details), that the sequences generated by Random for two distinct seed values would start with the same number in the range 48..57

Comment: `System.Random` isn't secure, use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that each time `charGen` is called, you create a new `Random`, which is initialized with the current clock for a seed. Since they are created so quickly, they all get the same seed.

You should create a single `Random` object at class level (or pass it to `charGen`).

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `Rnd()` instead of `Random`?

```
Private Function charGen() As Char
  Return Chr(Asc("0"c) + Rnd() * 10)
End Function
```

Then just call `Randomize()` before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Membership.GeneratePassword method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.generatepassword(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(int length, int numberOfNonAlphanumericCharacters)